# Have I missed anything? user1 is not in the sudoers file

Tags: ubuntu, users, privileges

I've created a user on a server where there was only root as:

```
# adduser user1
```

with a password. Then

```
# su - user1
```

And then:

```
$ apt-get update
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
user1@my_server:~$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for user1:
user1 is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
```

I believe I've missed something such as add some privileges or something like that.

How to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

Where we would get, if every new user would be able to `sudo` by default? This is administrator privilege. Ubuntu is using group `sudo` to give users this privilege.

If you want to allow user to run `sudo` for everything, add him to the `sudo` group:

```
useradd -G sudo user1
```

If you want to limit the user more, you should check how `sudoers` file look like and adjust it to your needs using

```
visudo
```

Comment: what about visudo file?

Comment: `visudo` is not a file, but program.

Comment: and where is the content of a program located? in the sky or in a file?

Comment: Program is `/usr/sbin/visudo`, but it should not matter. It is editing `/etc/sudoers`, but it should not matter either. What is the problem?